# How to override the container class in Bootstrap 4 HTML

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web application with Python Flask and am using the CDN Bootstrap for general styling
However I am testing things out to customise some components of Bootstrap and am trying to give a background colour to the .container class. Is there anyway to do this or the container class does not allow overriding of the style?

HTML DOC

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil assumenda laudantium rerum nam delectus at, accusamus natus iure reprehenderit unde, accusantium adipisci neque quaerat velit excepturi. Quo eaque veniam suscipit.
  </div>
</body>
</html>


CSS file
.container{
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? The code should add a background color to the container class

Comment: What is the issue? With the code given, it should display a container with black background color with Lorem Ipsum..content in it. Please be specific! If background-color property doesn't work, then add `!important` to the property.

Comment: The container does not have a background color with the code given, and I have no idea what the issue is as well. Adding !important doesnt change anything as well

Comment: Is path completely correct?? Can you try...```<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/main.css?version=12">``` ... Sometimess caches make it difficult..

Comment: I tried viewing my page source and clicked on my css link. This returned me a css I saved before this. I completely deleted my main.css file and recreated one with one line of css, but the page source still shows my old css and nothing I update on the new css file is showing. I tried restarting my computer and rerunning the app, deleting the pycache folder but nothing works

Comment: Did you try in a different browser? If yes, is there any change in result?

Comment: When i tried in a new browser, it works for the first time. Afterwards if I update my css file and refresh the browser, the css on the site stays locked at the one I had the first time. Is there something that caches the memory of the old css file?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap container inside one more div tag or use some css in a seperate linked style sheet and make sure the css file comes after the link to the bootstrap.css file in the page code.

```css
CSS file
.container{
  background-color: black !important;
}

.color--black {
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div  class="color--black">
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil assumenda laudantium rerum nam delectus at, accusamus natus iure reprehenderit unde, accusantium adipisci neque quaerat velit excepturi. Quo eaque veniam suscipit.
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```